# solve recurrence relation $a_{n+2}=(a_{n+1}+1)/a_n$

Tags: recurrence-relations, characteristic-polynomial

Let $a_1$ = 2015, $a_2$=2016. Find $a_{2017}$, given $a_{n+2}=(a_{n+1}+1)/a_n$
I have found the 2 roots of the characteristic equation $x^2-x-1=0$ :
$r_1 = ((1+\sqrt{5})/2)^n$ , $r_2 = ((1-\sqrt{5})/2)^n$
Then I have used a calculator to find that the coefficients a and b are -57.418 and 56.7999 respectively. However every calculator treats raising to the power of 2017 as an error. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: How did you arrive at that characteristic equation? Is the recurrence relation even linear in the first place? $\quad$ Also, what kind of error do you get, is it an overflow where the number is too large to handle?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @CalvinLin I let a_(n+2) = x^2, and a_(n+1)=x, and a_n=1. Is that not correct? And no, doesn't look linear, do characteristic roots not work for non-linear equations? And yes, the error is oveflow

Comment: @JohnDoe Characteristics equation methods work for linear equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note $a_{1} = 2015, a_{2} = 2016, a_{3} = \frac{2017}{2015}, a_{4} = \frac{2}{2015},a_{5} = 1, a_{6} = 2015, a_{7} = 2016,...$

Thus the sequence repeats modulo $5$. Hence $a_{2017} = a_{2} = 2016$.

You cannot use characteristic equations (as pointed out by other people such as jjagmath).

Comment: Thank you, that solves it! Although I have a question about $a_4$, how do you get it to be 2/2015? I can only get the answer on a calculator, but is there a way to get that fraction by hand?

Comment: Well... I used wolfram alpha

Answer (score 2):

Calling $a_1 = c_1$ and $a_2 = c_2$ we have

$$
\cases{
a_1 = c_1\\
a_2 = c_2\\
a_3 = \frac{c_2+1}{c_1}\\
a_4 = \frac{c_1+c_2+1}{c_1c_2}\\
a_5 = \frac{c_1+1}{c_2}\\
a_6 = c_1\\
a_7 = c_2\\
\vdots
}
$$